# Firebase Hosting: add '/#/' to start of path if not there

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

I have a flutter web app, in which paths are displayed as "www.example.com/#/path/to/page"

I want to be able to redirect anyone who clicks on a link to "www.example.com/profiles/user1" to "www.example.com/#/profiles/user1"

How can I use redirects to achieve this? If not, are there other solutions?

Comment: Check [URL strategy](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/url-strategies) configuration

Comment: The problem with pathUrl strategy is that it reloads the entire app if the user navigates manually via address bar. This doesn't happen with the HashURL strategy. This is important because reloading the whole site results in all the singeltons/logic having to reinstantiate which causes lag. So I'm looking to stick with the hashurl strategy, but I want to allow users to type in a non-hash url, and just have firebase redirect it to the correct hashurl